# Should I be using JVM or JRE on client's machine to run Embedded Java DB?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have compiled and build my application in Netbeans which includes Java DB.  Now in order for everything work in client environment, should I have them install JRE or JVM??! Does JVM include the embedded Java DB support?!

Comment: By "Java DB," do you mean [HSQLDB (aka Hypersonic aka HyperSQL)](http://hsqldb.org/)?

Comment: Just a terminology note, you mean JDK and JRE, both have a JVM.

Comment: No Java DB is meant to e embedded in Java applications without having a third part application installed  http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/ref-single.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the JRE should suffice.

For running anything that you have built the client only needs to install the JRE. You only need to the JDK to compile your work and preforming diagnostics using jconsole.

And the java db is basically a java program. Its just like a program that you would have written. So the JRE does not need anything special to start it in the embedded mode or in the network client-server mode.

Comment: So all I need to do is to include the derby.jar files and that's it, isn't it??!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the JRE does not come with Java DB.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html

Wouldn't it be better to just distribute everything you need with your application?